# WP7 WebBrowserTask without url entry textbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

This might not be possible but I thought I'd check with everyone.

Is it possible to load a WebBrowserTask on WP7 but to have the url entry box collapsed? I'd also like to set IsHitVisble to false?

The reason I want to do this is to load a url (through databinding) but ensure that the user can't browse to other links on the page. I also need to keep the phones share control in the tool bar so I can't just use a webbrowser control and set the source to the url.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: create your own "share" button?

Comment: I did think about this but it would be good to leverage off what the phone already provides if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can use a `WebBrowserControl` inside your own app, but it's not recommended.

Basically such odd/weird limitations as this, don't belong in any modern day craftsmanship. And thus why it isn't a possibility (thanks Microsoft!)